# How to create MVC Database First application with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datasource, ef-database-first

I can use MS SQL in MVC application, but now I want to create MVC Database First application with MySQL (MVC 4, VS 2012, MySQL 5.5). I can connect to MySQL in Server Explorer window. When I create new **ADO.NET Entity Data Model**, there is not MySQL in data sources list.

[image]

How can I create my first application with MySQL?

Comment: try it? http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/12/09/getting-mysql-work-with-entity-framework-4-0.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I had installed MySQL Connector/NET, but I installed it from VS Extensions and Updates window, then it worked