# How to use Mysql Database in MVC Entityframework

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-4, ado.net, entity-framework-6

[How to use mysql Database in mvc Entityframework. Please show below image. I want to use .net framework data provider for mysql same as sql server. what i can do? [https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDlTe.jpg][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDlTe.jpg)

Comment: Possible solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997652/how-to-create-mvc-database-first-application-with-mysql?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You should downlaod the MySql provider and follow the documentation [MySQL Connector/Net doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html)